# Stop keypress event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keypress

How to stop `keypress` event in `keydown`.

I have a `keydown` handler in that I need to stop `keypress` event.

Actually I have a form and textbox in it.

When user press <kbd>enter</kbd> key, `keydown` is triggering the event and having the handler.

Form submit will triggered be in `keypress`, so I need to stop the `keypress` event in my `keydown` handler.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
function onKeyDown(event) {   
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault

or

```
function onsubmit(event) {
  return false;
}
```

return false to stop events propagation

Comment: var suppressEvent = false;
function onKeyDown(event) {
  suppressEvent = true;
  event.preventDefault();
}
function onKeyPress(event) {
  if (suppressEvent) event.preventDefault();
}

Comment: Thank you so much @john. This helped me with an issue I was having where my custom event handler caused the enter key to move to the cell below in an html table _AND_ was adding an unnecessary extra new line in that new cell. I just needed to cancel the default event of the enter key.

Answer (score 5):

Here I stopped the event bubbling for up/dn/left/right keys:

```
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
    });
```

I also tried *e.preventDefault* or *event.cancelBubble = true* from the answers above, but they had no impact.

Answer (score 4):

In opera, you have to use the `keypress` event to prevent the default actions for keyboard events. `keydown` works to prevent default action in all browsers but not in opera.

See [this long list of inconsistencies](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) in keyboard handling across browsers.

Comment: `keyPress` is now [**obsolete**](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#obsolete_events).

Answer (score 1):

Write,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function keyDn(obj)
      {
        if(window["event"]["keyCode"]==48)  // key 0 will disabled keyPress event
         {
           obj["onkeypress"]=null;
          }
       }
      function keyPs(obj)
      {
        alert("Keypress");
      }

    </script>

  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <input type="text" onkeydown="keyDn(this)" onkeypress="keyPs(this)" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

in keydown handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try `event.cancelBubble = true` in event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the event.preventDefault(); to work in Safari and Firefox, but not IE7 or IE8.

If you only want to disable the enter key, make sure that you're also checking for the key value (13 for Enter) and only setting event.preventDefault() for that key.

Anyone able to come up with an answer for IE7/8 or Opera?

Comment: I know this is a very old thread, but as your question is still not answered, I will. In fact I recently found a working workaround for the problem you specified:

You make your form return false onsubmit and hide and disable your submit button. Then you create a second button (which is not of the type submit) which infact will remove the return false property of the onsubmit event and removes the disable of the button aswell. After that you use this button to simulate the click event on the real submit button. You can find a working example here: 

http://jsfiddle.net/rsauxil/qyf8L/6/ .

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="form-control select-calender" placeholder="Choose Date" value="" required >

$(document).on('keypress','#date',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.