# How to stop keypress event in keydown

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I stop `keypress` event in keydown handler?

Comment: What is your exact need?

Comment: whatever type in textbox i need to get the text and should not reflect the typed text into textbox..

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404583/stop-keypress-event

Comment: You asked this before! (I voted to close this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't stop the keypress even from keydown... they're both very separate events. What you can do is cancel the keydown / keypress after reading the character. Here's what I do to allow only letters and numbers to by typed into a text box (jQuery)

```
  urlBox.keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which == 13 || e.which == 8 || e.which == 0) return true;
            if(48 <= e.which && e.which <= 57) return true;
            if(65 <= e.which && e.which <= 90) return true;
            if(97 <= e.which && e.which <= 122) return true;
            return false;                 
          });
```

Comment: I don't think its browser dependent. Anyway, you could also call prevent default if you want to be safe. Look up the docs for that.