# Preventing user from inserting *

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to prevent user from inserting * in a textbox.
This is what I was trying to do, but here it only detects * if this is the only inserted character. For example texts like: *,  etc.
When allowed characters are mixed with *, then it cannot detect it. For example inputs such as: *hjh, etc..
and maybe how to make it replace only * with "" and not the whole field?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testField(field) {
        var regExpr = new RegExp("[^*]");
        if(!regExpr.test(field.value)) {
            field.value = "";
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="searchGamesKeyword" class="searchGamesTextBox"
name="searchGamesKeyword" onblur="testField(this);" />
```

Comment: use keyup event and check keycode.

Comment: Please don't use `new RegExp` with a static string. JavaScript offers `RegExp` literals, which are better in a lot of ways. `var regExpr = /[^*]/;`

Comment: Also, please don't try to cancel this dynamically; just show a message beside the field. It's difficult to get selections right in this case, and it's just generally annoying when typing stuff doesn't work. (Although selections aren't an issue right now, I think clearing the entire textbox after the user inserts one wrong character is a little more annoying.)

Comment: @minitech: heh, nice catch. :)

Comment: don't use regex for this. it's way better to check for the keycode on the keyup event as @OZ_ said

Comment: @MartinSchaer or @ OZ_- can you please explain? thanks..

Comment: I suggest you _don't_ change to use key events for this because the user might paste without using the keyboard.

Comment: @user990635 see my answer below, it takes into account copy & pasting. but remember to check at the back end too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
function testField(field) {
    field.value = field.value.replace(/\*/g,"");
}
```

Called from `onblur=testField(this)` as shown in the question it will take the current value of the field and replace any and all asterisks with an empty string, leaving all other characters untouched. So, e.g., `"ab*cde*"` would become `"abcde"`.

The `g` on the end of `/\*/g` is a flag meaning to match globally - without this flag it would just replace the first match.

The reason your code didn't work is that your regex of `[^*]` will match (i.e., return true from `.test()`) if there is a non-asterisk character anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to anchor your regexp to the start and end of the string: `new RegExp("[^*]")`

Try this: `var regExpr = /^[^*]*$/` -- it asks for zero or more instances of any character except `*` anchored at the start and end of the string. Maybe `/^[^*]+$/` would be better (note `+`) if you want to force one or more instances of any character except `*`.

Comment: I updated my post with [minitech's advice to use RegExp literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130896/preventing-user-from-inserting/11130921#comment14587870_11130896) -- thanks @minitech.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testField(field, event) {
    if (event.charCode == 42) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }    
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="searchGamesKeyword" class="searchGamesTextBox"
name="searchGamesKeyword" onkeypress="javascript:testField(this, event);" />​
```

Comment: And here comes [the selections problem I mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130896/preventing-user-from-inserting#comment14587881_11130896). If the user is typing somewhere in the middle of the field, the cursor will keep jumping to the end. Not a good experience.

Comment: oh I see what you mean, hm, you will need to capture the keypress and preventDefault(), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421562/how-to-stop-keypress-event-in-keydown

Comment: Unrelatedly: you don't need both the escape and the character class. Just use `/\*/g`.

Comment: Yup - and once you handle the key events, then you get the problem with the user copying and pasting the invalid characters in. It's a lose-lose-lose situation.

Comment: Good point, though you could always filter those out on the back end. I updated my answer anyhow.

Comment: @jchook Actually your first script worked, and this one doesn't spot the * :P

Comment: You *probably* need to check for a combination of `8` and `shiftKey`; but that's not the same on all keyboards. Try `keypress`; it offers `keyChar` for reliable checking.

Comment: @minitech it will be typed through different mobile phones.. will key checks work in that case?

Comment: Huh, worked for me in jsfiddle before. I updated answer based on @minitech's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

This should prevent people typing * and copy and pasting it to. Remember to check on the back-end to, because people may have JS disabled in their browsers.

Javascript:

```
function testField(f)
{
    var o='',i,v=f.value;
    for(i=0;i<v.length;i++) if(v[i]!='*')o+=v[i];
    f.value=o;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchGamesKeyword" class="searchGamesTextBox" name="searchGamesKeyword" onkeyup="testField(this);" onchange="testField(this);" />
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/martinschaer/Sbg6w/ (manually optimized and minified ;))

EDIT:
Using a flag (`c`) you can avoid having the caret positioned at the end if you try to edit what you've typed so far. Like this:

```
function testField(f)
{
    var t,c,i=0,o='',x="value",v=f[x],l=v.length;
    while(i<l){t=v[i++];if(t!='*')o+=t;else c=1}
    if(c)f[x]=o
}
```

​Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/martinschaer/Sbg6w/

Comment: I wouldn't do that on keyup (or any key event) because updating the `.value` will tend to move the cursor to the end of the field, making it very tedious to edit an existing value. (You could add a separate keyup handler to prevent that character being entered, with your current function from `onchange` or `onblur` taking care of any pasted changes.)

Comment: @nnnnnn and how about adding a flag to update f.value only if an * has being detected? that would eliminate the problem when trying to edit a value. I insisted to do this onkeyup too so the user gets that * are not allowed, instead of making them disappear when he finished typing... for me your solution is more than fair enough :P