# Suppressing keypress in onKeyPress, but onChange still fires

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function which I've tied to the onKeyPress event of my ReactJS component:

```
onKeyPress(e) {
  if (!isNumeric(e.key) && e.key !== '.') {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This executes properly in that if the input is not numeric (eg. "b"), it will return false.  The issue, though, is that the `onChange()` event linked to the control is still firing.  I would expect that if you suppress the keyboard input, nothing will change and the `onChange` event won't fire.  That does not appear to be happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop keypress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404583/stop-keypress-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an extension to the number provided by @Joel

```
onKeyPress(e) {
  if (!isNumeric(e.key) && e.key !== '.') {
    e.preventDefault();
    //return false; Not needed
  }
}
```

You only need `e.preventDefault()`, `return false` can be excluded

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `preventDefault()` on the event as to stop default event bindings. Modify your code to this for the fix:

```
onKeyPress(e) {
  if (!isNumeric(e.key) && e.key !== '.') {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Can you add a snippet and prove it.

Comment: Duh. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: It does work, just that you might need to change `isNumeric` to `Number.isInteger`, else your console will showing undefined function isNumeric

Comment: `e.key` is always a `string`.
So, you need to do this to test if `e.key` is a number or not : 
`if (Number.isNaN(parseInt(e.key, 10)) && e.key !== '.')`

Comment: I was only speaking to e.preventDefault(), which absolutely works.